# How can I use an IBOutlet from another Class file into a different .m file?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

MyGems.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@interface MyGems : UIViewController {

    IBOutlet UIImageView *lock1;
```

Collect.m

```
#import "Collect.h"
#import "MyGems.h"

@implementation Collect

- (IBAction) unlock {

    if (lock1.hidden = NO) {

        ruby.hidden = NO;
    }
```

- I get 4 errors, can someone please help? It seems to simple, but is confusing me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should almost never do this. The view controller (`MyGems`, which should be named something like `MyGemsViewController`) is responsible for managing this view. Other classes should not reach in and modify its IBOutlets. Doing so will cause you significant problems when the view managed by MyGems unloads and `lock1` surprisingly becomes nil.

It's unclear what `Collect` is in this case; I assume it is another view controller? I'm not clear why `unlock` isn't a method on `MyGemsViewController`.

Also note that this code is incorrect, and should be throwing warnings at you telling you it's incorrect:

```
if (lock1.hidden = NO) {
```

This *assigns* `NO` to `lock1.hidden`. You meant to use `==`, but you should never test against `NO` this way. You should do it this way:

```
if (! lock1.hidden) {
```

You must be careful of testing booleans against `YES` and `NO`. There are many true values that do not equal `YES`.

Comment: & I cannot make MyGems a ViewController, because this is a UINavigation application, forgot to mention.

Comment: MyGems *is* a ViewController. `@interface MyGems : UIViewController` What do you mean? Have you read the View Controller Programming Guide for iOS? http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure you have a reference to lock1 in your Collect class, most likely you will want to achieve this by having a reference to the Collect class in MyGems and then moving this view logic back into MyGems rather than in your Collect model class

Comment: Can you please post a small code snippet on how to do this? I rarely deal with these problems. Thanks!